# How sound transmisson differs in closed muffled room from open space?

Tags: waves, acoustics

I wonder, how differs behaviour of sound in two different localization: First, we have open space - only ground and no obstacles. Second, we have a tiny closed room with well-muffled walls.

I was thinking like this:
In the first scenario, the sound will spread out without any echo. In the second the sound will be absorbed by walls (so in no case the sound returns). That leads me to the conclusion that the human will hear an undistinguishable sound (imagine a person will be speaking and listening to his own voice) in these two locations.

Am I right? Or will the listener distinguish between absorbed sound by walls and spread sound in open-air?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having worked in an anechoic chamber in a previous lifetime, being inside one is exactly like being in the open air in a completely quiet place- if you are talking about sound frequencies associated with music or human speech. Those frequencies are especially well-absorbed by the walls.

But for sound frequencies where the wavelength is similar to the major dimensions of the room, it stops being anechoic- although it remains fairly well-damped. since your ear is relatively insensitive to low frequencies, the chamber sounds anechoic even though it isn't.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!